# How to hash a crontab job using sh script

Tags: sh

I am running a job using crontab. Which is mentioned below.

```
*/30 * * * * wget http://test.co.in/Mail/print.php
```

I want to add hash using sh script.

```
#*/30 * * * * wget http://test.co.in/MailAlert/print.php
```

I couldn't get solution from anywhere. So could you please help me anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to perform this task, you can simply use **sed** in your script to add hash in your crontab.
In ubuntu crontab file is at /etc/crontab

```
sed -i "s/*\/30 * * * * wget http:\/\/test.co.in\/Mail\/print.php/#*\/30 * * * * wget http:\/\/test.co.in\/MailAlert\/print.php/" (path of cronjob file)
```

Another way of editing the crontab using Bash is something like that

```
echo "#*/30 * * * * wget http://test.co.in/MailAlert/print.php" | tee -a /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

Comment: i have tried your command but that is showing **sed: no input files**

Comment: Use this path at the end of your sed command, (/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root), check that path and you will find your all cronjobs here !

Comment: I am receiving this following error: **-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ** for the command sed -i "s/*\/30 * * * * wget http:\/\/test.co.in\/Mail\/print.php/#*\/30 * * * * wget http:\/\/test.co.in\/MailAlert\/print.php/" (/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root)

Comment: you have to provide the path at the end of the command without round brackets, i have just put them for showing you.

Comment: Thank you so much. it has reduced my headache.